# How to set an image as a frame around a responsive image?

Tags: html, image, css

I have a frame as jpg, something like this:

[image: just an image found via google images, only used to ask this question]

Inside this frame, I want to display an image. I want the frame to resize along with the image inside.

What is a good way to do this with CSS?

First I thought of the goold old tables.

Then I thought I could use the [multiple background images feature from CSS3](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/). But that still feels a little hacky.

Are there any better/simpler solutions?

Comment: Multiple background is not a hack (it is in the spec). If you dont want to use multiple background just use 2 tags and style them.

Comment: multiple bg: http://jsfiddle.net/1uu8m118/1/
2 div's with bg: http://jsfiddle.net/1uu8m118/2/

Comment: I guess it feels hacky, because I have to use 8 background images or more.

Comment: `border-image` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to set width 100% to have image responsive and to manipulate with paddings to  show background of this image.

Example:
HTML

```
<div>
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/benjigarner/softdimension/256/Image-ready-CS-2-icon.png" /></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

img {
    padding: 50px 15px 30px 20px;
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Result:
http://jsfiddle.net/pzy6wg3f/2/

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but you did not get to the core of my question.